# Speed difference between using int and unsigned int when mixed with doubles

Tags: c++, c, performance, x86

I have an application where part of the inner loop was basically:

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i, ++data, ++x) sum += *data * x;
```

If x is an unsigned int, then the code takes 3 times as long as with int!

This was part of a larger code-base, but I got it down to the essentials:

```
#include <iostream>                                      
#include <cstdlib>                                       
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

typedef unsigned char uint8;

template<typename T>
double moments(const uint8* data, int N, T wrap) {
    T pos = 0;
    double sum = 0.;
    for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i, ++data) {
        sum += *data * pos;
        ++pos;
        if (pos == wrap) pos = 0;
    }
    return sum;
}

template<typename T>
const char* name() { return "unknown"; }

template<>
const char* name<int>() { return "int"; }

template<>
const char* name<unsigned int>() { return "unsigned int"; }

const int Nr_Samples = 10 * 1000;

template<typename T>
void measure(const std::vector<uint8>& data) {
    const uint8* dataptr = &data[0];
    double moments_results[Nr_Samples];
    time_t start, end;
    time(&start);
    for (int i = 0; i != Nr_Samples; ++i) {
        moments_results[i] = moments<T>(dataptr, data.size(), 128);
    }
    time(&end);
    double avg = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i != Nr_Samples; ++i) avg += moments_results[i];
    avg /= Nr_Samples;
    std::cout << "With " << name<T>() << ": " << avg << " in " << (end - start) << "secs" << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    std::vector<uint8> data(128*1024);
    for (int i = 0; i != data.size(); ++i) data[i] = std::rand();
    measure<int>(data);
    measure<unsigned int>(data);
    measure<int>(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with no optimization:

```
luispedro@oakeshott:/home/luispedro/tmp/so §g++  test.cpp    
luispedro@oakeshott:/home/luispedro/tmp/so §./a.out
With int: 1.06353e+09 in 9secs
With unsigned int: 1.06353e+09 in 14secs
With int: 1.06353e+09 in 9secs
```

With optimization:

```
luispedro@oakeshott:/home/luispedro/tmp/so §g++  -O3  test.cpp
luispedro@oakeshott:/home/luispedro/tmp/so §./a.out
With int: 1.06353e+09 in 3secs
With unsigned int: 1.06353e+09 in 12secs
With int: 1.06353e+09 in 4secs
```

I don't understand why such a large difference in speed. I tried figuring it out from the generated assembly, but I got nowhere. Anyone have any thoughts?

Is this something to do with the hardware or is it a limitation of gcc's optimisation machinery? I'm betting the second.

My machine is an Intel 32 bit running Ubuntu 9.10.

**Edit**: Since Stephen asked, here is the de-compiled source (from a -O3 compilation). I believe I got the main loops:

int version:

```
40: 0f b6 14 0b             movzbl (%ebx,%ecx,1),%edx
     sum += *data * pos;
44: 0f b6 d2                movzbl %dl,%edx
47: 0f af d0                imul   %eax,%edx
      ++pos;
4a: 83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
      sum += *data * pos;
4d: 89 95 54 c7 fe ff       mov    %edx,-0x138ac(%ebp)
      ++pos;
      if (pos == wrap) pos = 0;
53: 31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
55: 3d 80 00 00 00          cmp    $0x80,%eax
5a: 0f 94 c2                sete   %dl
  T pos = 0;
  double sum = 0.;
  for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i, ++data) {
5d: 83 c1 01                add    $0x1,%ecx
      sum += *data * pos;
60: db 85 54 c7 fe ff       fildl  -0x138ac(%ebp)
      ++pos;
      if (pos == wrap) pos = 0;
66: 83 ea 01                sub    $0x1,%edx
69: 21 d0                   and    %edx,%eax
  T pos = 0;
  double sum = 0.;
  for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i, ++data) {
6b: 39 f1                   cmp    %esi,%ecx
      sum += *data * pos;
6d: de c1                   faddp  %st,%st(1)
  T pos = 0;
  double sum = 0.;
  for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i, ++data) {
6f: 75 cf                   jne    40
```

unsigned version:

```
50: 0f b6 34 13             movzbl (%ebx,%edx,1),%esi
      sum += *data * pos;
54: 81 e6 ff 00 00 00       and    $0xff,%esi
5a: 31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
5c: 0f af f0                imul   %eax,%esi
      ++pos;
5f: 83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
      if (pos == wrap) pos = 0;
62: 3d 80 00 00 00          cmp    $0x80,%eax
67: 0f 94 c1                sete   %cl
  T pos = 0;
  double sum = 0.;
  for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i, ++data) {
6a: 83 c2 01                add    $0x1,%edx
      sum += *data * pos;
6d: 89 bd 54 c7 fe ff       mov    %edi,-0x138ac(%ebp)
73: 89 b5 50 c7 fe ff       mov    %esi,-0x138b0(%ebp)
      ++pos;
      if (pos == wrap) pos = 0;
79: 89 ce                   mov    %ecx,%esi
7b: 81 e6 ff 00 00 00       and    $0xff,%esi
      sum += *data * pos;
81: df ad 50 c7 fe ff       fildll -0x138b0(%ebp)
      ++pos;
      if (pos == wrap) pos = 0;
87: 83 ee 01                sub    $0x1,%esi
8a: 21 f0                   and    %esi,%eax
  for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i, ++data) {
8c: 3b 95 34 c7 fe ff       cmp    -0x138cc(%ebp),%edx
      sum += *data * pos;
92: de c1                   faddp  %st,%st(1)
  for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i, ++data) {
94: 75 ba                   jne    50
```

This is the -O3 version, which is why the source lines jump up and down.
Thank you.

Comment: That's quite odd.  How many timing tests did you run?  Generally if I find a 3x multiple I have to question if there were any background processes occurring at the same time.  Have you run 10 such tests?

Comment: Out of personal interest I'd love to see the assembly generated by that code, but my guess (totally unsupported by fact, merely a gut feeling) is that Intel probably optimized floating point conversions to signed integers because floats are signed, and a conversion to an unsigned integer requires extra data marshaling.

Comment: If you post the disassembly for the unsigned loop, I'll write up a detailed description of where exactly your cycles are going =)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's why: many common architectures (including x86) have a hardware instruction to convert signed int to doubles, but do not have a hardware conversion from unsigned to double, so the compiler needs to synthesize the conversion in software.  Furthermore, the only unsigned multiply on Intel is a full width multiply, whereas signed multiplies can use the signed multiply low instruction.

GCC's software conversion from unsigned int to double may very well be suboptimal (it almost certainly is, given the magnitude of the slowdown that you observed), but it is expected behavior for the code to be faster when using signed integers.

Assuming a smart compiler, the difference should be much smaller on a 64-bit system, because a 64-bit signed integer -> double conversion can be used to efficiently do a 32-bit unsigned conversion.

**Edit:** to illustrate, this:

```
sum += *data * x;
```

if the integer variables are signed, should compile into something along these lines:

```
mov       (data),   %eax
imul      %ecx,     %eax
cvtsi2sd  %eax,     %xmm1
addsd     %xmm1,    %xmm0
```

on the other hand, if the integer variables are unsigned, `cvtsi2sd` can't be used to do the conversion, so a software workaround is required.  I would expect to see something like this:

```
    mov       (data),   %eax
    mul       %ecx            // might be slower than imul
    cvtsi2sd  %eax,     %xmm1 // convert as though signed integer
    test      %eax,     %eax  // check if high bit was set
    jge       1f              // if it was, we need to adjust the converted
    addsd     (2^32),   %xmm1 // value by adding 2^32
1:  addsd     %xmm1,    %xmm0
```

That would be "acceptable" codegen for the unsigned -> double conversion; it could easily be worse.

All of this is assuming floating-point code generation to SSE (I believe this is the default on the Ubuntu tools, but I could be wrong).

Comment: That's btw what GCC does even in 32 bit mode: extending the 32 bit unsigned to a 64 bit signed and convert it with a 64 bit floating point load instruction.

Comment: Seems like I won't be using unsigned int for performance sensitive code.

Comment: Although Intel calls its 32x32->32 multiply instruction `IMUL`, its operation is equivalent to multiplying two 32-bit `unsigned int` in C (a signed multiplication in C would be allowed to do anything whatsoever if the product is outside the range of `int`).  I'd also expect that conversion of an `unsigned int` to `double` would simply promote to a `long long`.  The tricky case would be conversion of an `unsigned long long`, since converting as a signed 64-bit quantity and then adjusting the result would give incorrect rounding semantics on machines without an extended-precision type.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code produced by VC++ 6.0 - no optimisation:

```
4:        int x = 12345;
0040E6D8   mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],3039h
5:        double d1 = x;
0040E6DF   fild        dword ptr [ebp-4]
0040E6E2   fstp        qword ptr [ebp-0Ch]
6:        unsigned int y = 12345;
0040E6E5   mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],3039h
7:        double d2 = y;
0040E6EC   mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-10h]
0040E6EF   mov         dword ptr [ebp-20h],eax
0040E6F2   mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],0
0040E6F9   fild        qword ptr [ebp-20h]
0040E6FC   fstp        qword ptr [ebp-18h]
```

As you can see, converting the unsigned does quite a bit more work.

Comment: VC6... Wow, kicking it old school.  Thought I was the only one on the planet still using that compiler.

Answer (score 1):

output with visual studio 2010 with intel Q6600... (note: I increased the loop count from 128*1024 to 512*1024)

release mode...

```
With int: 4.23944e+009 in 9secs
With unsigned int: 4.23944e+009 in 18secs
With int: 4.23944e+009 in 9secs
```

debug mode...

```
With int: 4.23944e+009 in 34secs
With unsigned int: 4.23944e+009 in 58secs
With int: 4.23944e+009 in 34secs
```

The ASM in release mode... (unsigned)

```
    for (int i = 0; i != Nr_Samples; ++i) { 
011714A1  fldz  
011714A3  mov         edx,dword ptr [esi+4]  
011714A6  add         esp,4  
011714A9  xor         edi,edi  
011714AB  sub         edx,dword ptr [esi]  
        moments_results[i] = moments<T>(dataptr, data.size(), 128); 
011714AD  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-1388Ch]  
011714B3  fld         st(0)  
011714B5  xor         eax,eax  
011714B7  test        edx,edx  
011714B9  je          measure<unsigned int>+79h (11714E9h)  
011714BB  mov         esi,edx  
011714BD  movzx       ebx,byte ptr [ecx]  
011714C0  imul        ebx,eax  
011714C3  mov         dword ptr [ebp-138A4h],ebx  
011714C9  fild        dword ptr [ebp-138A4h]  //only in unsigned
011714CF  test        ebx,ebx  //only in unsigned
011714D1  jns         measure<unsigned int>+69h (11714D9h)  //only in unsigned
011714D3  fadd        qword ptr [__real@41f0000000000000 (11731C8h)]  //only in unsigned
011714D9  inc         eax  
011714DA  faddp       st(1),st  
011714DC  cmp         eax,80h  
011714E1  jne         measure<unsigned int>+75h (11714E5h)  
011714E3  xor         eax,eax  
011714E5  inc         ecx  
011714E6  dec         esi  
011714E7  jne         measure<unsigned int>+4Dh (11714BDh)  
011714E9  fstp        qword ptr [ebp+edi*8-13888h]  
011714F0  inc         edi  
011714F1  cmp         edi,2710h  
011714F7  jne         measure<unsigned int>+3Dh (11714ADh)  
    }
```

The ASM in release mode... (signed)

```
    for (int i = 0; i != Nr_Samples; ++i) { 
012A1351  fldz  
012A1353  mov         edx,dword ptr [esi+4]  
012A1356  add         esp,4  
012A1359  xor         edi,edi  
012A135B  sub         edx,dword ptr [esi]  
        moments_results[i] = moments<T>(dataptr, data.size(), 128); 
012A135D  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-13890h]  
012A1363  fld         st(0)  
012A1365  xor         eax,eax  
012A1367  test        edx,edx  
012A1369  je          measure<int>+6Fh (12A138Fh)  
012A136B  mov         esi,edx  
012A136D  movzx       ebx,byte ptr [ecx]  
012A1370  imul        ebx,eax  
012A1373  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1388Ch],ebx  
012A1379  inc         eax  
012A137A  fild        dword ptr [ebp-1388Ch]  //only in signed
012A1380  faddp       st(1),st  
012A1382  cmp         eax,80h  
012A1387  jne         measure<int>+6Bh (12A138Bh)  
012A1389  xor         eax,eax  
012A138B  inc         ecx  
012A138C  dec         esi  
012A138D  jne         measure<int>+4Dh (12A136Dh)  
012A138F  fstp        qword ptr [ebp+edi*8-13888h]  
012A1396  inc         edi  
012A1397  cmp         edi,2710h  
012A139D  jne         measure<int>+3Dh (12A135Dh)  
    }
```

interesting... with release mode and SSE enabled..... (fld and flds instructions removed but 4 instructions added)

```
With int: 4.23944e+009 in 8secs
With unsigned int: 4.23944e+009 in 10secs
With int: 4.23944e+009 in 8secs


    for (int i = 0; i != Nr_Samples; ++i) { 
00F614C1  mov         edx,dword ptr [esi+4]  
00F614C4  xorps       xmm0,xmm0  //added in sse version
00F614C7  add         esp,4  
00F614CA  xor         edi,edi  
00F614CC  sub         edx,dword ptr [esi]  
        moments_results[i] = moments<T>(dataptr, data.size(), 128); 
00F614CE  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-13894h]  
00F614D4  xor         eax,eax  
00F614D6  movsd       mmword ptr [ebp-13890h],xmm0  //added in sse version
00F614DE  test        edx,edx  
00F614E0  je          measure<unsigned int>+8Ch (0F6151Ch)  
00F614E2  fld         qword ptr [ebp-13890h]  //added in sse version
00F614E8  mov         esi,edx  
00F614EA  movzx       ebx,byte ptr [ecx]  
00F614ED  imul        ebx,eax  
00F614F0  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1388Ch],ebx  
00F614F6  fild        dword ptr [ebp-1388Ch]  
00F614FC  test        ebx,ebx  
00F614FE  jns         measure<unsigned int>+76h (0F61506h)  
00F61500  fadd        qword ptr [__real@41f0000000000000 (0F631C8h)]  
00F61506  inc         eax  
00F61507  faddp       st(1),st  
00F61509  cmp         eax,80h  
00F6150E  jne         measure<unsigned int>+82h (0F61512h)  
00F61510  xor         eax,eax  
00F61512  inc         ecx  
00F61513  dec         esi  
00F61514  jne         measure<unsigned int>+5Ah (0F614EAh)  
00F61516  fstp        qword ptr [ebp-13890h]  
00F6151C  movsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [ebp-13890h]  //added in sse version
00F61524  movsd       mmword ptr [ebp+edi*8-13888h],xmm1  //added in sse version
00F6152D  inc         edi  
00F6152E  cmp         edi,2710h  
00F61534  jne         measure<unsigned int>+3Eh (0F614CEh)  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran this on gcc 4.7.0 on a 64 bit machine running Linux.
I replaced the time calls with calls to clock_gettime.

CPU:       Intel X5680 @3.33 GHZ

GCC flags: -Wall -pedantic -O3 -std=c++11

Results:

```
With int time per operation in ns: 11996, total time sec: 1.57237
Avg values: 1.06353e+09
With unsigned int time per operation in ns: 11539, total time sec: 1.5125
Avg values: 1.06353e+09
With int time per operation in ns: 11994, total time sec: 1.57217
Avg values: 1.06353e+09
```

Evidently on my machine/compiler unsigned is faster.

Comment: It might be that newer gccs are better. If you are on 64 bits, it is, in any case, a different machine. Thanks for the info!