# Significant performance decrease from 'int' to 'long int'

Tags: c++, performance, int, long-integer

I've programmed simple implementation of sieve of Eratosthenes for calculating primes in given range. Initially I planned to use `long int` as main integer type. Calculating all primes lesser then 10 milion took something between 11-12 seconds. But when I switched type to `int`, I was getting about 4-5 seconds instead. Therefore I wonder - why is it?

I understand that `long int` takes more space than `int`, but I'm running 64-bit CPU - so - if I understand correctly - it has ALU that accepts 64-bit integers i.e. instructions on such numbers can be executed in same number of cycles. My prior research revealed similar questions beeing asked about performance difference between `unsigned` and `signed` types ([here][1] or [here][2]), but I'm using `signed` variables and I still get performence drop for the same (lesser then 2^33-1) input. Below I post my full code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    unsigned long int X, i, j;
    bool *prime, *primeFill;
    std::fstream outFile;
    clock_t T;

    /* user interaction */
    std::cout << "This applet will export all prime number from range (0, X). Enter desired X value: "; 
    std::cin >> X;

    primeFill=new bool [X]; 
    for (i=2; i<X; i++) 
        primeFill[i]=false;

    prime = new bool [X]; 

    /* main loop, where all actual computation happens */
    T=clock(); i=2;
    while(i<X) {
        prime[i]=true, primeFill[i]=true;
        for (j=2*i; j<=X; j+=i) prime[j]=false, primeFill[j]=true;
        while (primeFill[i]) 
            i++;
    }

    T=clock()-T;   

    /* outputing results to textfile & standard output */
    outFile.open("primes.txt", std::ios::out);

    for (i=2; i<X; i++)
        if (prime[i]) 
            outFile << i << '\n';

    outFile.close();
    std::cout << "Finished. Computation took " << (1000*float(T)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " ms\n";
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT New code above doesn't produce such problem. Refer to my answer below.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Are you sure that you are compiling for a 64bit architecture?

Comment: What is the size of the `long int`?

Comment: Look at the disassembly, is the compiler generating 32-bit or 64-bit instructions?

Comment: Measure the time for the `ceil` and `sqrt` functions for both 64 bit and 32-bit.  Is the compiler using the 32-bit versions in 64-bit mode?

Comment: ... **why are you using `isPrime` for Sieve of Eratosthenes?** You missed the point. Also, you're on Unix-like system if `long` and `int` makes a difference, is that right? The algorithm, even if properly implemented requires a lot of memory and is not cache friendly.

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r @Thomas Matthews I'm running [Intel i5-4570](http://ark.intel.com/pl/products/75043/Intel-Core-i5-4570-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz). Both `uname -a` and `file main` are showing `x86-64`. I use GCC 5.3.0. [Here](http://pastebin.com/raw/1ke7ZnyP) I posted detailed output of these commands.
@LogicStuff Yes, I'm running Linux 4.6.

Comment: You can speed up your algorithm by having the `for` loop start at 3 and increment by 2.

Comment: Your formatting is amusingly bad.

Comment: `new bool[X]` wastes a colossal amount of space

Answer (score 0):

As @LogicStuff correctly pointed out, I missed the point of Sieve of Eratosthenes by using `isPrime()` function. I've edited the code (edited original question) and now the same test (calculating primes lesser than 10 milion) takes between 250 and 300 miliseconds despite integer type - I've tested `int`, `long int`, `unsigned int` and `unsigned long int`.

This means that source of the problem was inside `isPrime()` function i.e. compilier or CPU lack either optimalization for `double` conversion or  `%` operator. I'm betting on the first one, because such problem was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043947/speed-difference-between-using-int-and-unsigned-int-when-mixed-with-doubles) for `unsigned int` as I mentioned in initial post. Thanks for all comments.